# Stuck at an infinite loop unless printing result

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, concurrency

I am trying to test a use case where I need to launch two threads, but the second one needs to wait for a particular state to happen.

The first thread launches the resolution process of a tournament in order to calculate its schedules. The second thread stops the resolution process.

```
@Test
public void stopResolutionProcessTest() throws InterruptedException {
    TournamentSolver solver = tournament.getSolver();

    Thread solveThread = new Thread(tournament::solve);
    solveThread.start();

    while (solver.getResolutionState() != TournamentSolver.ResolutionState.COMPUTING);

    Thread stopThread = new Thread(solver::stopResolutionProcess);
    stopThread.start();

    solveThread.join();
    stopThread.join();

    assertEquals(TournamentSolver.ResolutionState.INCOMPLETE, solver.getResolutionState());
}
```

The main thread gets stuck in the `while` loop, as if it were infinite.

However, if I just print the resolution state inside the loop, the test runs as expected:

```
while (solver.getResolutionState() != TournamentSolver.ResolutionState.COMPUTING)
    System.out.println(solver.getResolutionState());
```

I have no explanation for this; I feel like I am back several years in the past when I was studying concurrency and unexpected things I couldn't explain happened.

Could anybody shed some light on what's going on?

**Edit:** alright I set my `getResolutionState()` as `synchronized` and that did the trick, but I still don't understand why this helps or why printing the state would render the described results.

Comment: Try adding empty curly braces after the while loop: `while (solver.getResolutionState() != TournamentSolver.ResolutionState.COMPUTING){}`

Comment: @FinbarrO'Brien I did, and the same thing happened. What makes you think the behaviour would be any different using a colon or empty braces?

Comment: My bad, I wasn't sure that your semicolon was ensuring the while loop didn't pass through to include the 'Thread stopThread' creation in the loop iteration. Semicolon after the loop does ensure the loop doesn't include the following statement as the loop body. I've learned something new today.

Comment: If that'd been the case the next line wouldn't even compile because `stopThread ` wouldn't have been declared...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `getResolutionState()` do?  If all it's doing is returning the value of some variable that you're expecting the other thread to update, then it's possible that the other thread already *has* updated it, but that the update has not become visible to `stopResolutionProcessTest()`.

If thread A sets some shared variable to a new value, the Java Language Specification does not require the new value to immediately become visible to any other thread.  In fact, it does not require the new value to *ever* become visible until the threads *synchronize* with each other in some way that establishes a so-called "happens before" relationship.

You can find thousands of questions on StackOverflow that talk about "HappensBefore"

One operation that affects the visibility of updates is entering or leaving a `synchronized` block.   The `System.out.println(...)` method uses `synchronized` blocks, so it would be no surprise if calling `println()` made a previously invisible update suddenly become visible.

---

If `getResolutionState()` is just a simple getter for a private variable, then one way to guarantee that the state change becomes visible to other threads is to declare it as a `volatile` variable.

Java guarantees that any update that one thread makes to a `volatile` variable (along with any other update that it made to any other variable *before* it touched the `volatile`) will become visible to any other thread that reads the same `volatile` variable.

Comment: I get the visibility part. But if Thread A (the one that launches the resolution process) sets the state to a new value (which indeed it does), why would it not be visible to the main thread? That variable is a member variable, particularly to the `solver`, it referes to the same instance. And we're polling that value in the `while` loop. Or am I misinterpreting the scenario?

Comment: @dabadaba: you simply have to accept the fact that without proper synchronization, there is no guaranty that a thread sees the updates made by other threads. Otherwise, you should stay away from multi-threading. Note that this is also the reason, why it appears to work when inserting a print statement. In the default implementation, the `PrintStream` found in `System.out` synchronizes all writes, so seeing the other updates then is an unreliable byproduct. In principle, the thread is still not guaranteed to see the updates then, it just happened to work in a particular JVM/JRE implementation.